# find and replace command for whole directory

Tags: linux, shell, vim

Is there any command in Linux which will find a particular word in all the files in a given directory and the folders below and replace it with a new word?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will replace in all files. It can be made more specific if you need only a specific type of file.  Also, it creates a `.bak` backup file of every file it processes, in case you need to revert. If you don't need the backup files at all, change `-i.bak` to `-i`.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/oldword/newword/g' {} \;
```

To remove all the backup files when you no longer need them:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.bak" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: -1 this is going to modify every file in the directory, even if it doesn't contain the word you want to replace.

Comment: @dogbane Yep, just as indicated in the sentence above the command.

Comment: hey man...magic worked...!!! thank you.....you have saved ma lot time..........

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following command:

```
grep -lR "foo" /path/to/dir | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

It uses `grep` to find files containing the string "foo" and then invokes sed to replace "foo" with "bar" in them. As a result, only those files containing "foo" are modified. The rest of the files are not touched.

Answer (score 3):

Not a single command but combination of several:

```
find /home/bruno/old-friends -type f -exec sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' {} ;
```

Example from [here](http://www.teachmejoomla.net/code/misc/sed-find-and-replace-in-folder.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control you could use a python script like:

- [http://xahlee.org/perl-python/find_replace_unicode.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170909140443/http://xahlee.info:80/perl-python/find_replace_unicode.html)
- [http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473828-regexplace-regular-expression-search-and-replace/](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/473828-regexplace-regular-expression-search-and-replace/)